# Effect of L2 regularization on Linear Regression

Tags: regression, regularization, linear, ridge-regression

I am starting with L2 regularization on linear regression.

Case without regularization:

- objective function $(Xw-y)^T(Xw-y)$
- parameters vector $w= (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.$

Case with regularization:

- objective function $(Xw-y)^T(Xw-y)+ \frac{1}{2}αw^Tw$
- parameters vector $w= (X^TX+αI)^{-1}X^Ty.$

How can you explain the effect on regularization based on the equations provided? How $w$ gets shrink, and what $w_i$ in particular, since $w$ is a vector? What should be the condition for the particular $w_i$s to shrink?

Just by looking at the equations I cannot say much right now although I know alpha is not negative positive.

Extra would be if you can explain me why the objective function is written in this form.